# firebase update multiples database realtime

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, firebase, update

estoy realizando un sistema de ventas con firebase y javascript, tengo productos y quiero modificar varios de ellos al mismo tiempo con el siguiente codigo solo me modifica el primero

```
 for (var i = 0; i < compra.length; i++) {
        if (compra[i].value!=0){
            var key=compra[i].getAttribute("key");
            var cantidadcompra=compra[i].value;
            refproductoeditar=refproductos.child(key);
            refproductoeditar.update({
                cantidad:cantidad-cantidadcompra,
            })
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La consola tira algún error?

Comment: Como estas obteniendo los valores de `compra` ?

Comment: suena como un problema en el loop, pero sin más código es dificil ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo menos en el código para `firebase` no parece haber problema. El problema seguro está en como estas consiguiendo los valores de `compra`.

Pueden estar sucediendo dos cosas

1. El objeto  `compra` solo tiene un propiedad, y que por casualidad es la primera de `firebase`.
2. El objeto `compra` solo tiene una de sus propiedades que coincide con los datos guardados en `firebase`. Si esto fuera cierto, verías un mensaje de error en la consola que mostrandote que estas tratando de actualizar en firebase datos que no existen.
3. Que solo una de las propiedades de `compra` tiene `value` que no sea `0`

Sugiero algunos cambios:

```
for (var i = 0; i < compra.length; i++) {
        if (compra[i].value!=0){
            var key=compra[i].getAttribute("key");
            var cantidadcompra=compra[i].value;
            // Usar variables internas para evitar conflictos
            var refProductoEditar = refproductos.child(key);
            refProductoEditar.update({
                cantidad: cantidad - cantidadcompra,
                        //  ^ de donde sale cantidad?
            })
        }
    }
```